# Passing parameters to WCF function from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wcf

I have a WCF function that takes a complex type as its input parameter. How do you I create and pass this complex type (object with properties) through the call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish your task. You can use the ASP.NET ScriptManager and have it create a JavaScript proxy to the WCF service or you can use jQuery's ajax functionality to do it too. I've included links to both examples below.

Using jQuery/ajax:
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Apr/21/jQuery-AJAX-calls-to-a-WCF-REST-Service

Using ScriptManager JS proxy:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2007/09/04/using-wcf-json-linq-and-ajax-passing-complex-types-to-wcf-services-with-json-encoding.aspx